# Vertical spacing textboxes with Bootstrap form-horizontal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `form-horizontal` created with Bootstrap 3 that looks like this:

[image: Desktop form]

When I shrink the viewport I'd like the "Start" and "End" textboxes have a whitespace gap between them. However, they are scrunched together:

[image: Mobile form]

What can I do to add vertical whitespace that looks consistent with the rest of the form?

Here is a Bootply workspace with my HTML: http://www.bootply.com/sfB9elzbrC

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="user_search">Who is this reservation for?</label>
            <input id="user_search" name="selected_user_id" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="tool_search">Which tool will be used?</label>
            <input id="tool_search" name="selected_tool_id" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="control-label" for="start">When will the reservation start and end?</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="start" name="start" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input id="end" name="end" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="End" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label for="additional_information">Would you like to include any additional information for the reservation? (For example, tool configuration settings).</label>
            <textarea name="additional_information" class="form-control" id="additional_information" rows="4"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='submit' id="create_reservation" class="btn btn-default" value="Create reservation">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to those DIVs:

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 resv">
        <input id="start" name="start" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
```

And use an  `@media` query to add the spacing:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .resv {margin-top:10px;}
}
```

Modified bootply: http://www.bootply.com/31cYqbtHEZ

Comment: Would there be a built-in Bootstrap way to do this rather than using custom code?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, but it's extremely common to tweak Bootstrap.